# What is the Packet Structure for Getting the settings of a Particular Mailbox in Plesk API

Tags: php, xml, plesk

I'm working with the Plesk API to create a mailbox manager as part of a CMS I'm writing.  I've managed to get the correct XML packet structures for viewing all mailboxes on a domain, and creating a new mailbox, as these are outlined in the Plesk API documentation.

Currently, however, I'm trying to find out if there is a way to get the settings of a specific mailbox (specified by the mailbox ID and/or name).  I need to get the name, mailbox quota and any aliases.  I can get these settings for every mailbox on a domain, but I was wondering if there's a way to refine this by mailbox ID as part of the packet request (rather than putting all of the mailboxes into an array and searching through them by ID).

Hope that makes sense!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use ["filter" in Plesk API](http://download1.parallels.com/Plesk/PP11/11.0/Doc/en-US/online/plesk-api-rpc/34498.htm), i.e. smth like

```
<packet version="1.6.3.0">
<mail>
<get_info>
   <filter>
      <site-id>12</site-id>
      <mailname>
              <name>ann</name>
      </mailname>
   </filter>
   <mailbox/>
</get_info>
</mail>
</packet>
```

I had no chance to test this API call, but the reference above should give you all missing details about this sample request